# CSS rule shadowing not always in effect

Tags: css, firefox

Why isn't the text in the selected element yellow like the "char_t" link above (They do have the same class). It looks like it should be yellow in the inspector but not in the rendered page. The web browser is Firefox 27.

[image: Example]

All rules as listed in the inspector:

```
    element {
    }
    td.paramtype a, td.memname a {
        font-weight: bold;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #544A00;
        color: #FFDF00;
    }
    a.el {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    a.el {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    a {
        color: #FF409F;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a {
        color: #50A000;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .memname td {
        font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    .paramtype {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .paramtype {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .memname {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .memname {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    body, table, div, p, dl {
        font: 14px/21px "Verdana","DejaVu Sans",sans-serif;
        letter-spacing: 0.125px;
    }
    body, table, div, p, dl {
        font: 400 14px/22px Roboto,sans-serif;
    }
    table.mlabels {
        border-spacing: 0px;
    }
    table.mlabels {
        border-spacing: 0px;
    }
    .memproto, dl.reflist dt {
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #80FF00;
        color: #2A5400;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 125%;
    }
    .memproto, dl.reflist dt {
        color: #2B5600;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    }
    body {
        color: #000;
    }
    body {
        color: #000;
    }
```

[Page source](http://milasudril.github.io/gabi/html/class_herbs_1_1_path.html)

Comment: Strange behaviour, justed tested in FF27.1(OSx). The site appeared as desired..

Comment: Seems to be fine for me. I tested it in different versions of FF.

Comment: Working Great with Firefox 26.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the visited property. So it seems like the inspector does not take that into account when listing the current style even though it lists the "computed" styles. FF Feature request or bug?

Comment: Bug, I guess. Also, I think it's the visited _pseudo-class_.